# How to use image that is stored to ImageField in the template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following the models.py:

```
class Insurance(models.Model):
area = models.CharField(max_length=100)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
insurance_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
area_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/image')
```

And this template:

```
                    {% for product in insurance.insuranceproducts_set.all %}
                    <li class="one_third btmspace-10 holder">
                    <figure><img src="{% static 'img/320x320.png' %}" alt="">
                        <div class="content">
                            <p><a href="{% url 'insurance:farmer_type' product.id %}">{{ product.title }}</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
```

The problem is the page needs to load short description about the product. Here
it needs load the image that is related to that insurance product. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good summary in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/usage/#how-do-i-use-image-and-file-fields

Try changing your image tag to::

```
<img src="{{insurance.area_photo.url}}" alt="">
```